# Create event in google sheets, and send

Tags: google-apps-script

Have google sheet with events.
Each row is a new event with start/end date, title and email address that I would like to sent the invitation to.

I have found this option however it doesn't seem to send invitations but just creating event

```
"function createCalendarEvent() {
let communityCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(""calendar_ID"");
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet());
let schedule = sheet.getDataRange().getValues());
schedule.splice(0, 2);
schedule.forEach(function(entry){
        communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[2], entry[0], entry[1]);
});
}"
```

I would like to send invitations to ppl who are about to join each of the meetings.
Sample spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kuInNuaRXNnj8SfwD2aT2BuwgU6cqSPAoLSVYFHzd9Y/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
communityCalendar.createEvent(entry[2], entry[0], entry[1]);
```

#### To:

```
communityCalendar.createEvent(
  entry[2],
  entry[0],
  entry[1],
  {
    guests: entry[3],
    sendInvites: true
  }
);
```

#### Reference:

- [createEvent(title, startTime, endTime, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#createeventtitle,-starttime,-endtime,-options)

Comment: Huge huge thanks Tanaike!
This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Bartosz Kowalczuk Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.